# Serialize Spring BindingAwareModelMap

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, serialization

Currently I'm trying to serialize a Spring bean called `BindingAwareModelMap`. I'm aware that that class implements serializable but it doesn't seem to be availble for some reason. In our controller method we have a `Map<String, Object>` that represents our ModelMap. When we try to serialize it, first we cast it to a `BindingAwareModelMap`, and try to call `writeObject()` on it, but sadly it won't compile. Is our approach right or should we be looking somewhere else? Following is the relevant code snippet. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
public String confirm(final Map<String, Object> model) {
    // stuff happens
    BindingAwareModelMap bindingAwareModelMap = (BindingAwareModelMap) model;

    bindingAwareModelMap.writeObject();
    // ^ This line fails to compile
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the answer, looks like its actually pretty basic. Here's what we used:

```
   BindingAwareModelMap bindingAwareModelMap = (BindingAwareModelMap) model;
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file");
   ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
   out.writeObject(bindingAwareModelMap);
   out.close();
   fos.close();
```